# How to find elevation of multiple points on a map on ArcGIS 9.3?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-9.3

I am working on the sewerage system of a city. I have the x and y coordinates of the station locations stored in EXEL format.
How can I use this data/file to extract the elevations of the stations ? 
please help on this regard. Thanks.

Ps : there are almost 2000 of such station locations so its not possible to 
find location manually.

Comment: Do you have a DEM available? And Spatial analyst?

Comment: What if there are 3 raster (DEM) file?
How can I input the raster file to cover all my points? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have ArcGIS 9.3 with the Spatial Analyst Extention.

- Add your data, trough add data button. Both the DEM and the Excel
  sheet.
- In the source tab, right click over your table data (from your excel), and choose Display XY Data;

[image]

- In the Display XY Data choose your X and Y Fields, and press OK. At
  this point, you should be seeing your XY data on the map canvas.
- In the Toolbox, choose Spatial Analyst tools > Extraction > Extract Values to Point

[image]

- In the "Input point features" choose therecently created Point Layer, and in the "Input Raster" your DEM;
- The final result will be what you asked, a Point Layer with the Raster Values.